# How to resize the frame of embeded image in mail composer using MFMailComposeViewController in iphone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have embeded a user image in message body of MFMailComposeSheet
in my iPhone app.

```
NSMutableString *messageBody = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body>"] retain];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedProfileImage)];
NSString *base64String = [self base64forData:imageData];

[messageBody appendFormat:@"<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; %@.</p>",textMessage];
[messageBody appendFormat:@"<p>REGARDS</p>"];
[messageBody appendFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'>  </b></p>", base64String];
[messageBody appendFormat:@"<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; %@.</p>",userName];
[messageBody appendFormat:@"<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; %@.</p>",userPhone];
[messageBody appendFormat:@"</body></html>"];
```

Require format is like as follows:

[image: Sample screen]

But the embedded image displayed in its actual size, and I need to display in 57x57 pixels. How do I fix the width and height of the image as 57x57?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `width` and `height` on the `img` tag?

Comment: have you ever heard of using CAPITAL letters in your question, if you expect good answers at least have the curtesy to make your question as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
[messageBody appendFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64  , %@'  style='width:57px; height=57px;'>  </b></p>", base64String];
```